# Conditionally deleting a managed object

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I need to call a method which contains this if statement.

```
if(fetchedObjects.count == 10){
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:10]];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

fetchedObjects is an array. My program crashes because objectAtIndex:10 doesn't exists yet. It seems as though the if statement condition is being skipped all together. All I want to do is

> If objectAtIndex:10 exists, delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One off situation. If count equals 10 then objects exist at indices 0 - 9. So you'll need count to == 11 or delete the object at index 9.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That small detail had completely slipped my mind.